# ImageViewer produce blank image on ipad but work fine on android and simulator

Tags: codenameone

Sorry for my english!!
1-I create a simple form (borderLayout) and put imageViewer inside
2-Build on server for debug
3- install app on ipad, samsung, LG etc..
4- on samsung, etc.. i see correct image, "TakePhoto.jpg"
on ipad i see only a blank white image
I can not use the label because I need zoom,panning and sliding
i tried to set image before and after add component..

```
    Image im = Image.createImage(out.toByteArray(), 0, out.toByteArray().length);
    Util.cleanup(inputStream);
    im = im.scaledWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth());
    //**********************
    //InputStream is = Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(file);
    //EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is, is.available());
    ImageViewer imageViewer = new ImageViewer();

    //imageViewer.setImage(im);
    takePh.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, imageViewer);
    imageViewer.setImage(im);
    takePh.revalidate();

    takePh.show();
```

many Thanks!

Comment: format your question correctly

Comment: The question is whether the image is "good" and I'm guessing it's a problem with the image itself not with the image viewer. The question is how did you fill `out` and did you close it after filling it?

Comment: inputStream = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + immagine);
                    imageio.save(inputStream,
                            out,
                            ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG,
                            Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight(), 1);
                    im = Image.createImage(out.toByteArray(), 0, out.toByteArray().length);inputStream.close();  produce blank white image

Comment: InputStream is =  Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(immagine);

                    EncodedImage imv = EncodedImage.create(is, is.available());I do not see anything in imageviewer but if i use label all work fine. 
I do not understand why only on ios